# how to save xmldocument to a stream

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlreader

I've already written code to parse my xml file with an `XmlReader` so I don't want to rewrite it. I've now added encryption to the program. I have encrypt() and decrypt() functions which take an xml document and the encryption algorithm. I have a function that uses an xml reader to parse the file but now with the xml document I'm not sure how to create the xmlreader.

The question is how to save my xml document to a stream. I'm sure it's simple but I don't know anything about streams.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        doc.Load(filep);
        Decrypt(doc, key);

        Stream tempStream = null;
        doc.Save(tempStream);   //  <--- the problem is here I think

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(tempStream))  
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            { parsing code....... } }
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can try with `MemoryStream` class

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument( ); 
MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream( );
xmlDoc.Save( xmlStream );

xmlStream.Flush();//Adjust this if you want read your data 
xmlStream.Position = 0;

//Define here your reading
```

Comment: According to the [docs on the Flush() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `Because any data written to a MemoryStream object is written into RAM, this method is redundant`. Should remove that from your answer since it is essentially a "noop".

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but thought it worth adding a method from this [nice little blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xmlteam/2009/03/31/converting-from-xmldocument-to-xdocument/). This edges out some less performant methods.

```
private static XDocument DocumentToXDocumentReader(XmlDocument doc)
{
    return XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(doc));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing to a file:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<FTPSessionOptionInfo><HostName>ftp.badboymedia.ca</HostName></FTPSessionOptionInfo>");

        using (StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
        {
            fs.Write(doc.InnerXml);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    XmlDocument document= new XmlDocument( );
    string pathTmp = "d:\somepath";
    using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( pathTmp, FileMode.CreateNew ))
    {
      document.Save(pathTmp);
      fs.Flush();
    }
```